# Use of otherwise

Tags: word-usage

> The graphs also confirm that method x closely approximates ground truth, compared to otherwise shifted curve of method Y.

Is the use of *otherwise* making sense here??
If yes, any suggestions whether it's *the otherwise* or *otherwise*?

Comment: No; the whole sentence is unclear. Is 'otherwise shifted' meant to mean 'shifted in a different way from the way the first one is shifted'?

Comment: Hi Edwin, No the other curve does not shift w.r.t original and this one gets shifted w.r.t the original curve.

Comment: On close examination, the graph of method X indicates that this method closely approximates [to?] ground truth, while the displaced/translated graph of method Y indicates that method Y doesn't.

Comment: approximates the ground truth?

Comment: Or simply  approximates ground truth

Comment: There seems to be an article missing in front of "otherwise".